# Windows saying my msi installer is a virus

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer

When I am downloading the msi installer that I just made windows disables the download because its a "virus" when its a simple python app that I made.

There is any way to get windows to trust my installer? maybe an installer scanner or something?

I couldn't find anything about it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Just like an executable file, an MSI must be digitally signed for Windows to "trust" it.

If you search the windows-installer tag for "signing", there are lots of Q&A to chew on, and this documentation might be a good place to start:
[Introduction to Code Signing](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/seccrypto/cryptography-tools) and [Sign Setup.exe and MySetup.msi](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/msi/sign-setup-exe-and-mysetup-msi)

Comment: It's actually not that simple.  Micosoft doesn't actually say what exactly the trust formula is.  A regular codes signing cert might not be trusted initially until the app has been seen enough to be trusted.  For more money, more vetting an EV cert can get you there faster.    Here's a useful link. https://www.advancedinstaller.com/prevent-smartscreen-from-appearing.html

Comment: Thank you for your message.

But how can I use the SignTool to sign my msi?

Also, the problem isn't this smartscreen thing. You cannot even install the msi file on your computer windows will delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make difference:

A. Warning from common browsers like Firefox/Chrome and especially Edge are almost present as soon your binary (EXE/MSI) isn't digitally signed with a key file belongs to a root certificate. These certificates are very expensive - so in this way almost all little developers would be potential hackers from the point of view of browsers... Don't worry about it too much.

B. If your Antivirus warns you or online database know the file as harmful you should be very carefully. Though there might exist some false positives and Windows Defender complains about programs turning off MS telemtry, these warnings can be considered as serious on average. You have to do the following steps to prevent that.

- Verify with [www.virustotal.com](http://www.virustotal.com) whether its only 1 or 2 entries or significantly more and whether the culprit is the installer (msi) or your actual game inside the installer. If your python exe is marked as malware, your packed msi will be too (though msi is absolutely clean).
- Never touch files in folder like these: "C:\Windows", "C:\Program Files", "C:\Program Files (x86)" and also not in "C:\ProgramData" without GUI. When using python limit changes to your game/save folder, "%AppData%\Renpy" and "%temp%"
- Be carefully with alternate multiple files in a short time as its the same behaviour like Ransomware has. Nobody knows your game is really harmless or not, they focus on how many files got changed in a specific amount of time (think about Doki-Doki Literature Club, how should computers know these behaviour is ok?).
- Give your game an individual icon (no joke). Besides its nice and the users are happy, it differs more and more from mass EXE files that are indeed malware can be found online.
- Same reason for file description, version number, company name ans so on - your exe earns reputation this way and won't flagged as malware so easily.
- Don't run hidden external programs or suppressing GUI or console window. Thats highly suspicious and the way hackers would do. Cut out all of them in your project if exist.
- If not for the financial cost, I'd recommend everyone to get a file certificate from authority added as trusted root certificate in windows. Signing files with such .pfx file is like a identity card and decreases false positive the most. Even the UAC banner becomes blue then and tells everything is ok.

After that verify with [www.virustotal.com](http://www.virustotal.com) again, the entries should become far less by now.